# xrandr - Issues using --left-of to set up a second display

Tags: xrandr

I have two monitors, DP-3 with 2560x1440 resolution, and HDMI-1 with 1920x1200 resolution. I want HDMI-1 to be displayed to the left of DP-3. When I run `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of DP-3` everything displays as intended, but when I use `--left-of` the entirety of what originally displayed on HDMI-1 gets displayed on the DP-3 monitor and the rest of what was originally displayed on DP-3 extends into the monitor of HDMI-1.

There is another thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553739/xrandr-issue-when-scaling-monitor-on-the-left-but-works-on-the-right?newreg=4b2634f9129741e2a37a047b006f5a8b) from a few years ago where someone was having a similar issue, but the solution posted doesn't work for me. It also is never explained why `--left-of` apparently messes with scaling.

I don't know if this helps, but I'm using i3 and LightDM as my windowing and display managers

Comment: Have you tried using `arandr` (a frontend for `xrandr`)? You can click and drag the displays to arrange them, set their resolutions, and then save the result as a shell script. You can then insert an `exec_always` line at the bottom of your i3 config to set the layout when i3 starts up.

Comment: When I use arandr it gives the exact same issue. It says that DP-3 is displayed on the left and HDMI-1 is displayed on the right. When I try to swap the two, everything is messed up like I originally described.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that while the displays are messed up, it seems like the environment still thinks the windows are in their original positions. Say a terminal screen on that was originally displayed on DP-3 gets shifted into the display of HDMI-1, I still have to click on the area where it originally was on DP-3 in order for me to interact with it.

Comment: Do you think it might be an nvidia graphics driver issue?